# Find two functions in $L_p(\Bbb R)$, whose product $f\cdot g$ does not belong to $L_p(\Bbb R)$.

Tags: measure-theory, normed-spaces

How can I find two functions in $L_p(\Bbb R)$, with their product $f\cdot g$ not belonging to $L_p(\Bbb R)$?

Comment: Take spike functions for example, $f(x)=|x|^{-\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ is greater than 0, and the function takes value from unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself.

Comment: You can easily show that the function above belongs to $L^p(B)$ for $p\in[1,\infty)$, $B$ being the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ iff $\alpha p<n$. Now pick $\alpha$ very very close to $n/p$ such that when you multiply them together, the exponent doesn't satisfy the required condition to be in $L^p(B)$.

Comment: Actually i would like a full response, for example: f(x)=.... g(x)=....

Comment: Just take f=g that's the beauty (: On a side note, spike functions are the most usual counter example for this type of questions IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a function $$f(x) = \begin{cases}|x|^\lambda,&|x|\le 1,\\0,&|x|>1.\end{cases}.$$
This function belongs to $L^p(\Bbb R)$ whenever $\lambda p>-1$.

The function $f^2$  belongs to $L^p(\Bbb R)$ whenever $2\lambda p>-1$.

Therefore, if $\lambda\in \left(-\frac{1}{p},-\frac{1}{2p}\right]$, then $f\in L^p(\Bbb R)$, but $f\cdot f\notin L^p(\Bbb R)$.